# Telegram бот на Python не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

(Эхо-бот из видео Хауди хо) Попытался запустить через консоль, вставив токен от BotFahter в конфиг, но бот не реагирует на /start и какие либо другие сообщения. Ошибок в консоли никаких нет и бот запущен. В чем проблема?

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_type=['text'])

def ans(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types) в обработчике указывается content_type**s**:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ans(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Доступные типы:

`text`, `audio`, `document`, `photo`, `sticker`, `video`, `video_note`, `voice`, `location`, `contact`, `new_chat_members`, `left_chat_member`, `new_chat_title`, `new_chat_photo`, `delete_chat_photo`, `group_chat_created`, `supergroup`_`chat_created`, `channel_chat_created`, `migrate_to_chat_id`, `migrate_from_chat_id`, `pinned_message`

Для добавления реакций на команды используется обработчик `commands`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

так же в обработчике может быть указано несколько команд:

`@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])`